# How I can use Android Media3 with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-media3

The official documentation says that the best way to implement it is to separate MediaLibraryService and MediaController.

The official examples show how to get a MediaController and MediaBrowser for use inside an Activity:

```
val sessionToken = SessionToken(context, ComponentName(context, PlaybackService::class.java))
val controllerFuture = MediaController.Builder(context, sessionToken).buildAsync()
controllerFuture.addListener({
  // MediaController is available here with controllerFuture.get()
}, MoreExecutors.directExecutor())
```

I just can't find any examples of using the Jetpack Compose. The solution, which is to pass MediaController as a parameter of the parent function to all child elements, seems to me very bad.

Is it possible to use a MediaController instance and pass it possibly through a ViewModel to all the places I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your `MediaController` instance inside your `ViewModel`. To create the `MediaController` future, you just need a `SessionToken` and a context.

If you make your `ViewModel` extend [AndroidViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel), you can access the app context inside it.

For example:

```kotlin
class MyViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

   lateinit var mediaControllerFuture: ListenableFuture<MediaController>

    fun onStart(sessionToken: SessionToken) {
        if (mediaControllerFuture.get().connectedToken != sessionToken) {
            MediaController.releaseFuture(mediaControllerFuture)
            val context = getApplication<Application>()
            mediaControllerFuture = MediaController.Builder(context, sessionToken).buildAsync()
            mediaControllerFuture.addListener({ setupPlayer() }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context))
        }
    }
}
```

Then, on your composables you just need a `MyViewModel` instance, which you can get using the `viewModel<MyViewModel>()` composable.

It probably doesn't solve the problem of passing the instance to your other composable. Maybe it masks it, as you can call the `viewModels<MyViewModel>()` everywhere to receive the same instance.

Another option is to use the [CompositionLocal](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/CompositionLocal) API to add the `MediaController` to your composition tree. Make sure you get familiar with this API before using it. But I guess adding a CompositionLocal is not so harmful as replacing the foundation ones.